# Laravel 6 check if a json field contains a value in a collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am trying to see if a user id is contained in a json field in my laravel collection. In my postgresql database I have a user_id field which contains a list of integers that pertain to my user model and table. I am aware in eloquent I can use the whereJsonContains method but I am not finding an equivalent method for a collection. How can I go about searching this user_id column for a specific user id?

Answer (score 0):

check the manual for the aviable methods list:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

In your case i guess that is about:

> where